# Bootstrap 3 make columns of a raw all the same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row and 2 columns in there which I am trying to make the same height as there are border lines top and bottom that should be alined, also box shadow.
I've tried tons of recommended solutions recommended here excluding the ones involving javascript, [How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height) and none worked. E.g. adding this CSS to the row class didn't work:

```
.equal {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

My CSS:

```
   
.contact .info  {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.contact .php-email-form {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```
  <section id="contact" class="contact">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="section-title">
          <h2>CONTACT</h2>     
        </div>
 
        <div class="row">   

          <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="email">
                <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
                <h4>Email:</h4>
                <p>email</p>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
                <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
                <h4>Telephone:</h4>
                <p>95 966 0</p>         
            </div>
            <div class="address">
                <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i>
                <h4>Messenger:</h4>
                <p>address</p>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
                <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
                <h4>Whatsapp:</h4>
                <p>745 2720</p>
            </div>
            <div class="phone">
                <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
                <h4>Telegram:</h4>
                <p>745 2720</p>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-7">
            <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">N</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="name">Mobile</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="name">F</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
              </div>
                 </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">T</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
              </div>
          
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">U</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="6" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="err">
                <div class="processing">Loading</div>
                <div class="error-message"></div>
                <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent.!</div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send</button></div>
            </form>
          </div> 

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This is not a feature of BS3. When I was using BS3 and needed equal heights on elements, I used a super friendly script called matchheight.js. If you're stuck with BS3 then it might be worth a look. It's super simple to implement and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be very specific with your css.

I added a border to your cols so you have a visual of the col height.

BS3 was not designed to work with flex, but that doesn't mean it can't.

##### Update:

Created 2 css classes `.d-flex`, and `.d-flex-item`

In CSS flex model `display:flex` items make their children *flex items* which by default stretch to fit their container's height.

This goes only one level deep so to make this work with your layout:

- `div.row` is a flex container
- `div.col-md-5`:

  - is a flex item of its parent: `div.row`
  - is a flex container to its child `div.info`

    - `div.info` is a flex item of its parent: `div.col-md-5`
- `div.col-md-7` is a flex item of its parent: `div.row`

All of this is to allow the flex items to stretch to their parent containers.  Setting a CSS `height` on any flex-item will override the default `stretch` for that item.

---

```css
/* No changes here to your css */

.contact .info {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.contact .php-email-form {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}


/* flex css, see your HTML class attribute */

.d-flex {
  display: flex;      
}

.d-flex-item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title">
      <h2>CONTACT</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row d-flex">
      <div class="col-md-5 d-flex-item d-flex">
        <div class="info d-flex-item">
          <div class="email">
            <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
            <h4>Email:</h4>
            <p>email</p>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
            <h4>Telephone:</h4>
            <p>95 966 0</p>
          </div>
          <div class="address">
            <i class="bi bi-geo-alt"></i>
            <h4>Messenger:</h4>
            <p>address</p>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
            <h4>Whatsapp:</h4>
            <p>745 2720</p>
          </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <i class="bi bi-phone"></i>
            <h4>Telegram:</h4>
            <p>745 2720</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-7 d-flex-item">
        <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="name">N</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="name">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="name">Mobile</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="name">F</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="name">T</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="name">U</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="6" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="err">
              <div class="processing">Loading</div>
              <div class="error-message"></div>
              <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent.!</div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The columns now match in height.

So what'd be the best way to make my CSS (added to original post) to extend to the full height of the columns? Thanks

Comment: Same idea, targeted flex css.  I'll modify my post and clean up the CSS